# Tower of Hanoi - simple algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

A simple recursive code for solving hanoi tower:

```
public static void hanoi(char A, char B, char C, int n) {
  if(n>0) {
    hanoi(A,C,B,n-1);
    System.ouit.println("moving from " + A + " to " + B);
    hanoi(C,B,A,n-1);
 }
}
```

Me and my fellow student were checking this code today and while we know how it works, we fail to understand the algorithm, meaning we would never think of a such solution.

I do remember that a teacher once said, we don't care how it's solved, we just assume it is. He was referring to the part where a function calls itself.

I do know that we are basicly solving hanoi towers in 2 steps. First moving all rings to C ( this is a code from teacher and in this case we want to move all rings to B not C ), then moving the biggest ring to B and then moving all remaining rings from C to B. I do understand that in the first call we are moving from A to C and in second from C to B. 
I wrote on a paper how the code executes and got correct prints, but still i do not understand. I understand but i dont understand, if you understand what i mean.

ps: i checked many videos and links i found, none gave me any worthy answers as to how would you think of a such algorithm out of the blue. This is different then, for instance fibonaccis sequence, which is logical. But this ...

edit: It is hard for me to even explain what i dont understand, i never had problems at programming before. I know how this code works, i can write the whole procedure on paper. I know how to solve hanoi tower. But if you were to give me an assignment to write an algorithm for hanoi towers, i would never think of this. I am looking at this code and i am saying, how the hell did this code give the correct printout ? I have a problem with this leap of faith, yet somehow this is how recursion works. Basicly for first 2 rings i have no trouble understanding that this algorithm works. But from then on, moving rings is different because you already have 2 rings sitting on a nail and you have to move them before you can move more rings and then put those old rings back. Eh, i never had problems at programming until now, this is really bothering me as this is only the beginning, its supposed to be so simple and logical that our teacher didnt even bother explaining how this works, he just gave us the code and moved on.

Comment: Hi, welcome on Stack Overflow. Can you add a specific question to your post please?

Comment: See [*Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs), Chapter 3, and [*Tower of Hanoi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi).

Comment: @trashgod, many thanks for your recommendation. Even CLRS don't cover this important topic. By the way, people should stop writing the mantra "Tower of Hanoi is one of the classic problems to look at if you want to learn recursion". Though very simple, the algorithm is not obvious at all and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the call to the `hanoi` function as "move the whole pile of `n` disks from spindle A to spindle B using spindle C as a spare".  If you're willing to assume it can be done, conceptualize it as the function call. It should be clear after a few minutes thought that this can be accomplished by moving the pile **above** the bottom disk, which has `n-1` disks, from spindle A to the spare, spindle C, moving the bottom disk to its destination spindle B, then moving the pile on the spare from C to B. Since moving a pile was assumed to be a function call, the pile moves are accomplished by the recursive calls before and after the move of the bottom disk. The only remaining issue is to recognize when there's no more to be done. That's accomplished by your `n` counter, which represents the number of disks in the pile to be moved. When it's zero, there's no action required.

Towers of Hanoi is a good example of the "recursive leap of faith," in which you assume the solution is possible with a function call and then just apply the function to one or more sub-problems + a trivial case.

Answer (score 0):

See if watching this helps: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/1b-procedures-and-processes-substitution-model/ starting from 47:15. These classes are amazing, not only historically. Among them, the Tower of Hanoi. Don't worry about the class given in lisp, it's the same principles.